# Making print layouts for an online form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So i have an online form that i made where people can fill out some personal info and submit it to a help desk department using HTML/CSS. I guess one of the requirements is to make a button that shows a print layout of the form. I'm pretty new to making forms or any web stuff. What do you web guys use to make print layouts? or am i going to have to just make another separate page using HTML/CSS that's just styled differently?

If anyone wants to even just point me to an easier solution that would be great. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use a media query and apply some CSS inside of it. Use `display: none;` for elements, that are unimportant for the print.

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */ 
}
```

See this link for more info: http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/